# Custom printing options using AirPrint and UIPrintInteractionController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, airprint

I've successfully added printing capabilities to an iPad application that makes use of the `UIPrintInteractionController` class. Things work well, and a standard document is printed.

There are a couple `BOOL` properties that can be defined for a print job in my application, however. (Turning on certain features, adding additional layout schemes, etc.)

How can these options be presented/modified by the user using the `UIPrintInteractionController`? The perfect solution would be to add a couple switch table view cells to the `UITableView` that is presented in that controller, but this doesn't seem to be allowed by the API.

**Edit:** This is the view I'm referring to:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the best bet (so far) is to assign a `delegate` to the `UIPrintInteractionController`, and have that delegate implement the method:

```
- (UIViewController *)printInteractionControllerParentViewController:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController
```

If the delegate returns an instance of a `UINavigationController`, then instead of being presented modally, it can be pushed from a `UITableViewController` subclass that provides a list of options.

From the `UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate` class reference:

> UIKit can push the returned view controller onto the stack if its
>   parent is a navigation controller or present it modally if it isn’t.

[UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate)

Comment: if I do the above said then I will also have to handle all other tasks , Right?

Answer (score 3):

Use `printInteractionControllerParentViewController`, the trick is to declare a `UINavigationController *aNav;` in `.h` and then in `viewDidLoad` do `aNav = [self UINavigationController];` this will save the `navigationController` handle (assuming self is a `UITableViewController` with `UINavigationController` setup ok).

Then after invoke the `uiprinterinteraction`, do `aNav.topViewController.viw.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` to change the `uiprinterinteraction` background color to red.

Lastly, in `printInteractionControllerParentViewController` do a return `aNav;`

Now you have successfully change the background color of the AirPrint ui.

By using this `aNav`, you can do a lot of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to subclass UIPrintInteractionController, there's no hint in the Class Reference that it's not possible.